# SharePoint Adding EventHandler to existing content type

Tags: sharepoint

I am working with a content type that originally had no event handlers defined in its content type definition.  There are lists on my site that use that content type.  I have since then added event handlers to the content type's definition.. am I right in assuming that the current lists on my site will not have the event handler tied to them (where as creating a new list with this content type would have the event handlers).

I understand that I can programatically add an event handler to a specific list, I would just like to clarify that this behavior is correct.. because other than that it appears to update other components of the existing list's content type such as adding new fields, etc.. so it's a little confusing as to what content type definitions have an impact on existing lists and which do not.

Comment: I guess I should note that the event handlers are defined in the content type definition (as well as fields), however there is also a list schema with field information, views, etc.. Maybe modifying the list schema impacts existing lists?

Comment: I'm pretty sure modifying the list schema does NOT impact existing lists.. only new ones. I would guess adding the event handlers to an already existing content type would NOT impact existing content types either. Semi-related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203132/sharepoint-adding-a-content-type-to-all-document-libraries

Answer (score 0):

I would try calling [SPContentType.Update(true)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms475889.aspx), which should push changes down to the lists:

> Updates the content type definition that is stored in the database and, optionally, updates all content types that inherit from this content type if the Boolean updateChildren parameter is set to true.